# defaultProps in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to use defaultProps in React Native?
I’ve tried the following 2 ways of defining defaultProps and I get null when trying to access the defaultProp

```
export default class Foo extends Component {
  // 1. define defaultProps within Class
  static defaultProps = {
    someData: 'Hello',
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.someData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View> {this.props.someData} </View>
    )
  }
}
  // 2. define defaultProps outside Class
Foo.defaultProps = { someData: 'Hello' }
```

Answer (score 19):

I always do it like this and it works just fine:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {};

Foo.propTypes = {
  animateBackground: PropTypes.bool
};

Foo.defaultProps = {
  animateBackground: false
};

export default Foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it in ReactNative

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class foo extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.array,
        prop2: PropTypes.string
    }
    static defaultProps = {
        array: [1, 2, 4],
        name: 'abc'
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Default Prop array is: {this.props.array}</Text>
                <Text>Default Prop name is: {this.props.name}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And then you can use these props like `this.props.prop1` and `this.props.prop2`.

Answer (score 0):

I uses in this way ,try this!

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

Example.defaultProps = {
  name: 'John'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want this:

```
Foo.propTypes = {
    someData: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

This says that `someData` should be a string, but it is not required.

Then in your `render()`, you can do this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View> 
        {this.props.someData || Foo.defaultProps.someData} 
      </View>
    );
  }
```

This will use `this.props.someData` if it's provided or `Foo.defaultProps.someData` if not.

I also think you need to wrap `{this.props.someData || Foo.defaultProps.someData}` in a `Text` element (i.e., `<Text>{this.props.someData || Foo.defaultProps.someData}</Text>`).