# how to set a default value for a headerLeft?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Inside of my component `render()` method, I'm doing the following:

```
    if (this.state.text) {
      this.props.navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: this.headerLeft,
      });
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: this.headerDEFAULT,
      });
    }
```

I would like to leave `headerLeft` as empty instead of `this.headerDEFAULT`, to go back to its default state. How can that be done?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035274/defaultprops-in-react-native?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is inside of screen then use `navigation.setOptions`

headerLeft prop is your custom component so you override it

```js
const navigation = useNavigation()
navigation.setOptions({headerLeft: (...props) => null})
```